# How do I hit a URL daily with PHP or Perl as a scheduled task in Plesk?

Tags: php, perl, plesk

I am using shared hosting on Windows. I need to run some code that will basically just hit a URL on my .NET site once a day.

I'm using Plesk. I have seen that I can create scheduled tasks in Plesk, but when I asked my hosting service provider they said I can only execute PHP or Perl scripts (and not Windows executables).

I have zero experience in PHP and Perl. How can I do this using either Perl or PHP? Are there any gotchas? Do i need to set anything else up on my server to run these scripts, or is it just a case of dropping these `.php` or `.perl` files somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

  file_get_contents('http://yoururl.com');
  exit();

?>
```

That will make a request to `'http://yoururl.com'`.  If you are not concerned with the response then this is the way to go.  All you have to make sure is that your server can execute php code - I think it's pretty safe to say that most servers today are able to do that.  Especially if its shared hosting.

You can place this in a cron job though your plesk control panel.

If you are allowed to execute system processes, you might also be able to get away with placing this command as the cronjob :

```
wget -O - 'http://yoururl.com'
```

From the `wget` [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) -

> **Wget - The non-interactive network downloader.**
>    Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It supports  HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval through HTTP proxies...

Comment: Yes you can - however in my experience, cURL is not installed by default (on unix systems) and if you were referring to the cURL with PHP - the syntax is much more verbose and overkill IMO for such a simple "execute and forget" command... IE: we don't really care about the response...

Comment: the version of plesk(virtuzzo) i'm using is for windows, it allows me to create scheduled tasks - I cant see anything for cron jobs is it the same principle for scheduled tasks?

Comment: @rak, yes - a cronjob **is** a scheduled task - sorry, I should have mentioned that :)

Comment: does this .php file have to sit in a specific directory or something?

Comment: That depends on your hosting service, but I'd say that you can place it anywhere on your server - preferably in a place that is not accessible to the public so that you don't get random users executing that script as well...